# RealmSwift error "Error integrating bootstrap changesets: Failed to transform received changeset: Schema mismatch:"

Tags: mongodb, realm, mongodb-atlas

I am working with RealmSwift and the Atlas Sync App.  I have made a breaking change in development mode and have received the following error.

```
"Error integrating bootstrap changesets: Failed to transform received changeset: Schema mismatch: Link property 'images' in class 'equipment' points to class 'EquipmentImages' on one side and to 'equipment_images' on the other."
```

I have updated my equipment class's property for images, which is an object of type EquipmentImages. The previous name for this class was "equipment_images", I changed it to "EquipmentImages".

The equipment property "images" with array of objects of type "EquipmentImages".

[image]

This is the new EmbeddedObject class.

[image]

The realm stored on the users device shows the proper naming for the images property.

[image]

The schema on Atlas Sync is as follows .

[image]

I can not get the Atlas Sync App to update the "images" property to show EquipmentImages, it is named with the previous name of "equipment_images".

When I go to the Atlas App SDKs section I see that the old class name is still presented for this list.

[image]

How can I get Atlas Sync to update from the old class name of equipment_images to EquipmentImages? I have tried to generate a new schema, I have tried to use developer mode, I have tried it without developer mode. I have terminated and restarted sync, and I have deleted the users realm multiple times. I can get everything to work and sync like it should with the old class name, but not when I change it.

Comment: That's a destructive change so you will likely need to delete your local files, terminate and restart sync using the Realm console, then everything should link up. If you have not reviewed it, take a look at [Update Your Data Model](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/sync/data-model/update-schema/#std-label-synced-schema-overview) and also [Remap a property name](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/object-models/#remap-a-property-name)

Comment: I did read that some changes will not occur unless you terminate sync and leave it terminated for at least 10 mins. I have not tried that yet. I will look into mapping, but what is the point of Developer Mode if it will not update the changes on the Atlas App side!?

Comment: Developer mode will absorb additive changes with a minimal effort. Destructive changes are much more 'severe'. That's one of the reasons when we first start on a project we only work locally. We'll have the Sync code in the app but our Realm singleton returns a local only Realm initially as it's much easier to work with; just delete the realm and re-add test data (for example) with a single click.